# Error 503, downloading a HUGE google spreadsheet to xlsx with Python

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, google-api, gspread

We have a huge google spreadsheet that needs downloading. It has around 15 sheets, 15k rows by 20 columns each. We also need to have formatting saved (like merged cells, colours etc) but its not our first problem. With help of chatgpt I've come to this mess of a code, but it does not seem to work even with a batch size of 5. I keep getting error 503 (API, server unavailable), but its obvious that the reason is the huge file, not the google servers being down. It keeps being stuck on the line with fetching values. My Python version is 3.10.12.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import gspread

# Set the path to your service account JSON file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'

# Set the ID of the Google Spreadsheet
SPREADSHEET_ID = 'my_spreadsheet_Id'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

def download_spreadsheet():
    # Authenticate using the service account credentials
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    # Open the Google Spreadsheet
    spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID)
    print('Spreadsheet opened successfully.')

    # Create a new workbook
    workbook = Workbook()

    # Fetch data for each sheet
    worksheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
    for worksheet in worksheets:
        sheet_title = worksheet.title
        print(f'Fetching values for sheet: {sheet_title}...')

        # Get the total number of rows and columns in the sheet
        total_rows = worksheet.row_count
        total_cols = worksheet.col_count

        # Set the batch size
        batch_size = 5

        # Calculate the number of batches for rows and columns
        num_row_batches = (total_rows - 1) // batch_size + 1
        num_col_batches = (total_cols - 1) // batch_size + 1

        # Create a new sheet in the workbook
        ws = workbook.create_sheet(title=sheet_title)

        # Fetch data in batches
        for row_batch in range(num_row_batches):
            start_row = row_batch * batch_size + 1
            end_row = min(start_row + batch_size - 1, total_rows)

            for col_batch in range(num_col_batches):
                start_col = col_batch * batch_size + 1
                end_col = min(start_col + batch_size - 1, total_cols)

                # Fetch values for the current batch, KEEPS BEING STUCK HERE
                print(f'Fetching values for row batch {row_batch+1}/{num_row_batches}, col batch {col_batch+1}/{num_col_batches}...')
                range_str = f'{sheet_title}!{chr(start_col + 64)}{start_row}:{chr(end_col + 64)}{end_row}'
                values = worksheet.get(range_str)
                print(f'Values fetched successfully for row batch {row_batch+1}/{num_row_batches}, col batch {col_batch+1}/{num_col_batches}.')

                # Convert the values list to a DataFrame
                df = pd.DataFrame(values)

                # Append the DataFrame to the worksheet
                for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
                    ws.append(row)

                # Pause for a few seconds to avoid rate limiting
                time.sleep(10)

        print(f'Values fetched successfully for sheet: {sheet_title}.')

        # Fetch formatting for the entire sheet
        format_rules = get_all_conditional_formatting(spreadsheet, sheet_title)

        # Apply formatting to the new sheet
        apply_formatting(ws, format_rules)

    # Remove the default sheet created by openpyxl
    workbook.remove(workbook['Sheet'])

    # Save the workbook as an Excel file
    output_path = '24234.xlsx'
    workbook.save(output_path)

    print(f'Data downloaded successfully and saved as {output_path}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_spreadsheet()
```

I feel like I've already tried everything possible I could find, like decreasing batch size, adding waiting time, iterating in fetching values (thats where it keeps being stuck, just on the first sheet). We just need that document downloaded, even if its better to use something else than python. Hopefully someone else also had this issue and resolved it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the details of the difference between the goal of your script and just exporting a Google Spreadsheet as XLSX data?

Comment: Is it impossible to download the file manually and process that?

Comment: It is impossible because of the amount of data in the spreadsheet. The download button just won't do anything. I am using python as a workaround

Comment: I faced the same error with Firestore while fetching tonnes of data some days ago. I think there is an inbuilt timeout for google.oauth2
I'd say, increase the batch size and save the data in a formatted str or something, once fetching is done, convert it back to xlsx and save it

Comment: For anyone encountering same issue in future, saving formatting is apparently not supported through API. I just copypasted and saved data manually in batches for the time being